# why Oracle Apex stops working with Google captcha after migration from 4 to 19?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, recaptcha

After migrating Oracle Apex from 4 to 19, google's catptcha service stopped working. When I try to log in, it gives the message ERR-1002 The item ID "g-recaptcha-response" could not be found. The validation with google seems to be ok, but Apex is not managing to handle the return.
I researched a lot but found only one topic on the subject, but there is no answer.
Does anyone have any idea what it might be?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We have the same error on APEX 19.2 and 20.1. It seems like APEX thinks the invisible `g-recaptcha-response` div added by the Google reCAPTCHA callback function is a page or application item.

We reached this conclusion because the debug log says "Unexpected error, unable to find item name at application or page level,” which is an error raised by "WWV_FLOW_META_DATA.FIND_ITEM_BY_NAME" from "WWV_FLOW.PARSE_PAGE_ITEMS_JSON_OBJECT."

This shows that `g-recaptcha-response` is being incorrectly passed as an application/page item on page submission and the internal APEX processing fails because it cannot find the item’s id.

We worked around this error by removing the `g-recaptcha-response` div before submitting the page. We concluded it was safe to do so after validating the client response against the Google API.

Try adding a true action to Execute JavaScript Code with `$( "#g-recaptcha-response" ).remove();` before submitting your page. That should eliminate the error.